# configure: error: GCC plugin headers not found; consider installing GCC plugin development package

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64, odb

I am trying to build and install odb runtime libraries using instructions from this http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/install-mingw.xhtml

While running configure for odb runtime I encountered the following error:

> checking dynamic linker characteristics... no
>   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
>   configure: creating ./config.lt
>   config.lt: creating libtool
>   checking for GCC plugin headers... no
>   **configure: error: GCC plugin headers not found; consider installing GCC plugin development package**

I operating system is win 7 64bit, I am using Msys2 with pacman manager. 
I attempted to install gcc headers using

> pacman -S gcc-plugin-devel

but recieved an error stating that pacman did not find this package.

**Question.** How do u install gcc plugin headers using pacman?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has to be directed to the library support, not SO.

Comment: You can't. There is no [pacman package for MYSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/Packages/) 
with a name that contains the strings `gcc` and `plugin`. The instructions
you are following seem murky to me.

Comment: @mike yes it seems such a package does not exist. I ditching mingw for now and I'll try building on a Linux machine.

Comment: Why do you want to build the odb compiler by yourself? There is a usable binary for windows on the vendors website.

Comment: @Superlokkus I was trying to build the odb compiler myself. In the end I gave up and used the binary provided.

Comment: Then better ask the pacman people, since it's not related to odb, that you can't install the gcc plugin headers on your system.